# How do I change my cursor manually?

Tags: 12.04, themes, cursor

I have the cursor theme that I want, but how do I install it? Do I have to move it to a folder, then go to Ubuntu Tweak or MyUnity for example and choose it from there?

Thanks

Comment: What type of file is it?  Are you running Unity?

Comment: @Mitch In the folder I have a index.theme file and a folder called "cursors" with many "image/x-xcursor" files in it. And I am using unity but that shouldn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

just copy your downloaded files to your .icons (ctrl+h to see it) folder located in your home directory. Create a folder then paste the index.theme, cursor.theme files and the folder of the cursors inside it. Use Ubuntu Tweak to choose it.

Comment: Thanks that worked but the cursor only changes when I'm in an application. Not on the desktop, or the file manager, etc. How do I fix this?